# rviz shows nothing when there is no error in the terminal

Tags: ros, rviz, roslaunch, package, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello professors, when I successfully run the package and there is no error showing on the terminal, but the rviz shows nothing and there is no model at all...So I'm so confused about this problem and I can't find where the problem is...
Thanks for your information.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124136/rviz-shows-nothing-when-there-is-no-error-in-the-terminal/) by [saina110](https://answers.ros.org/users/11076/saina110/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2014-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default, there will be no display types (except maybe a grid). You need to click the "Add" button under the list of displays and add relevant displays for your robot. You may also need to adjust the global frame in "Global settings". See http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes for a list of display types available.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1